# socat to log serial port data

Tags: serial-port, socat

I want to log and display a stream of data arriving at a serial port in hex with timestamps and all non printable characters (particularly any XON XOFF characters). don't need to transmit anything on the Tx port, it is not connected.

Been trying to use stty to set port parameters and socat to log but having trouble.

using /dev/null socat just exits without any doing any thing, using -u and /dev/null as second address doesn't show or log anything, using a PTY as second address works for a while but then hangs - I guess the PTY fills up and block with nothing reading it.

Thanks for any help.